# How to expand all the tree list filters in ag-grid by default?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

By default all the filters in the tree list are collapsed. We need to click on the expand button to expand these filters. Is there a way to expand all the filters by default?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynQBk.png

There is nothing given about this in the official documentation